# How to disable the create account from express checkout?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, whmcs

I am using PayPal with WHMCS. During the purchase, PayPal express checkout popup shows the create PayPal account form also below the credit card information form, and this [Create your PayPal account] form is required even after doing [these](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/admin/checkout-settings/) changes as per the PayPal documentation.

On the other side, the WHMCS also doesn't have any option to disable/hide the create PayPal account form.

[image]

Due to this issue, my clients are getting annoyed and leaving my site without completing the purchase. How to disable the create account from express checkout?

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal flow for new PayPal buyers. An option to pay without creating an account might sometimes be available, depending on many factors including the buyer's location, but is never guaranteed.

---

For the option of a black button to pay with a Debit or Credit Card to always be available, integrate with [current PayPal Checkout buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which for a UAE buyer will look like this:

[image]

You can test [the demo here](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client) and append `&buyer-country=AE` to the SDK script line (only for sandbox mode)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to disable the Create PayPal Account from the checkout with Black Button permanently? I am using it with the WHMCS and I don't have access to the source code file of the WHMCS.

Comment: You can imagine how difficult it would be when a customer is going to checkout and he got stuck in the registration, provide national id, date of birth, and so on. I am losing many customers daily because of this issue.

Comment: If the bottom black button expands an inline credit card form, it will not ask for account creation. (The top yellow PayPal button will open a popup window, some buyers must use an account there.)

Comment: So there is no guarantee that the create account form will always be hidden?

Comment: That form is normal functionality of the top ("PayPal") button when the user doesn't have an account. If the form were somehow hidden, they wouldn't be able to pay with PayPal. You can't control what's within the PayPal window.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but incase anyone else is trying to solve it, I've just used simple CSS to hide it - using the default Twenty One theme I just added this to my custom.css file.

```
.express-checkout-buttons {
display:none;
}
```

And it hides. I know its not the best option but it works for me as I don't need to my clients checking out via this option.

Comment: I think the point of the question avoiding requiring the user to input those fields. Using display none will only hide the elements, but the validations will still execute.